# Windows 7 wifi reports "no network access" and "no internet access" but connects in fedora

Tags: windows-7, laptop, wifi-driver

I am running windows 7 home basic (64bit) on a Acer 5742G laptop with Atheos wifi adapter in it. Yesterday, I hiberneted my computer as I always do and up untill then the wifi was working fine. When I booted my computer up again today I started having a strange problem: It detects my wifi but after connecting to it, it keeps on oscillating between states of **no network access** and **no internet access**. I can't connect to anything (the internet or my router). I tried to reset my internet protocol stack using [this fixit file](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/299357). I also tried to uninstall and reinstall my network driver. Neither helped.

I am using the same laptop's fedora installation right now and the wifi is working perfectly fine. Please help.

**Edit**
To add additional details, I have Microsoft Security essentials as my antivirus software and I haven't messed with the firewall or the router configurations.

Comment: Out of curiosity you didnt flip the wireless on/off switch did you?

Comment: Yeah I did that too. I turned off then on again my router and my wifi adapter.

Comment: updating my wireless driver trashed some of my connections some days ago. Have you tried deleting the wireless connection profile and reconfigured it?